# 2004 Toyota Vitz Trunk not opening

Tags: toyota, fuse-panel, trunk, vitz, actuator

I have a 2004 Toyota Vitz (Right Hand Drive, imported from Japan).   Very recently it became impossible to open the boot/hatch.  To open the boot hatch I would typically make sure the car is unlocked, and then press the button (switch) on the center of the hatch panel.

I managed to pop the boot open from the inside (by removing the covering panel and pushing down a lever.    I have then proceeded to do some crude diagnostics.  I discovered 2 connectors to this mechanism.  The one on the left (looking into the boot) appears to be a 2 wire contact switch which is closing when depressed.

I note that the central locking of the doors works (but suspect that the problem occurred when I unlocked the car - the rear passenger side door did not open, I then tried again and it did - which has not happened before.   Subsequent to this the boot did not open, but the rear passenger door again opens reliably)

Looking at the door mechanism -

The cable that routes to the right appears to control the actuator has 4 wires.  I am able to measure ground and 12 volts on 2 of the pins.  The third pin appears to send a short pulse (but is difficult to read with a digital multimeter) when the remote is pressed, but I was unable to detect any kind of voltage change/signal when the boot switch was depressed (on any of the pins)

I hope and suspect that the problem is fuse related.  I have checked all the 11mm fuses on the fuse panel in box but I find it *extremely* difficult to reach in and pull fuses on the indoor panel.     The panel is written in Japanese, and the descriptions of the "Fuse box in passenger compartment Toyota Yaris" at https://fusesdiagram.com/toyota/fuses-and-relay-toyota-yaris.html does not seem to list anything relevant - and I just noticed is talking about the fuse box being in the passenger compartment when mine is on the driver side - although the fuse box layout matches the description.

Questions:

- Does anyone know if the problem is a fuse, and if so, which fuse I need to pull?
- Are there any things I should be doing to diagnose and fix the problem?